# "Neighbours spotted smoke <((to) be) coming> <(to) come> out of the house."

Tags: verbs-of-perception, catenative-verbs

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spot_2):
**(1)** *Neighbours spotted smoke **coming** out of the house*.
As far as I understand, the following that-sentences are correct too:
**(2a)** *Neighbours spotted (that) smoke **came** out of the house*. – correct
**(2b)** *Neighbours spotted (that) smoke **was coming** out of the house*. – correct

I'm interested in whether other variants may be used after the verb "*spot*":
**(3)** *Neighbours spotted smoke **to be coming** out of the house*.
**(4)** *Neighbours spotted smoke **be coming** out of the house*.
**(5)** *Neighbours spotted smoke **to come** out of the house*.
**(6)** *Neighbours spotted smoke **come** out of the house*.

Tell me please which of (3), (4), (5) & (6) are correct and which are not?

Comment: Please don't just make random guesses about structures. It's a waste of everyone's time. Things that you have reason to believe are correct, sure, but this is a list of pure guesses.

Comment: 2a is grammatical but not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spot), the verb **spot** can be followed by an object, an -ing verb, a question-word or **that**. Sentences 3 to 6 are therefore incorrect.

Regarding sentence 6, the word **[see](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see)** can also be followed by a bare infinitive, though I would only use it in a situation where something happened just once. For example, if there were just one plume of smoke, you could say:

> Neighbours heard an explosion and saw smoke come out of the house.